# Ethernaut - token challenge

Tags: overflow

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Token {

  mapping(address => uint) balances;
  uint public totalSupply;

  constructor(uint _initialSupply) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply = _initialSupply;
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] - _value >= 0);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }
}
```

The contract instance gives `msg.sender` 20 token. I know how `overflow` attack works, what I can't understand is that how does `require` check passes when someone calls the transfer function `transfer(0x0, 21)`, where `20-21 is negative!`

Require does not look for overflow, it is a simple check but solution to challenge somehow works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know why..

`balances` maps the address to `uint`. Inside the require check, `uint - uint = uint`, where `20-21 = -1` which underflows the uint... This is nasty.

Comment: Doesn't uint-uint = uint = -1, result in overflow as unsigned integer is always > 0.? Does not it result in 2 ^ 256 -  2??

Comment: No, not really. For simplicity think uint 2^8 which the minimum value can be 0. However, -1 will underflow it. It will turn -1 to [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] which is 255.

Comment: Ya so, 255 is greater than 0. So it passes the require clause

Answer (score 0):

If i remeber the case here was that you send to your self(to) a big number(value) (maxUINT NUMBER).
So you will finish the code with :
balances[_to] += _value;
*where to is your address 
*and value =very large number

Summary :
You will send to yourself a very big number (maxuintnumber ).
 And finaly you will finish with  
balances[_to] += _value; <br and you will get a big number in your balance

Comment: no need for very big number, even if you pass big number, the brwser will give an error.